# Adobe AIR packager yields Unable to open destination file: ... Info.plist in Application Loader

Tags: iphone, sdk, air, flash-cs5, packager

I have an app in the App Store that I produced using the Adobe AIR 2.0 packager back in March 2011.  Now, the client wants to update it.  But, I can no longer upload an update.

I get the following error when using the Application Loader:

> Unable to unzip application. Underlying reason: Unable to open destination file: /var/folders/05/d7xltrms59j0n1bplx_nvwr0000gn/T/Protocols.ipa/Payload/ProtocolsSmall.app/Info.plist, No such file or directory.

Looking inside the IPA, Info.plist is certainly in there.

I tried using new provisioning and new certificates, I tried using Java 32-bit, I tried reinstalling Flash CS5.  I tried the 2.5 SDK (I can't using anything higher though).

I wonder if this packager is creating an outdated IPA that Apple no longer accepts.  Ideas anyone?

Comment: I was using Application Loader 1.5 (that comes with Xcode 4.1).  I upgraded to Application Loader 2.4.1 and now I get this message: _This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK or Xcode._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.  I used the AIR 2.5 SDK and PFI.  Then, I upgraded Application Loader to 2.4.1 and that did the trick.

To download AIR 2.5 SDK, go to the Adobe archives: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/853/cpsid_85304.html

To download an updated version of PFI, go to the following link:

MAC:
http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flash/updates/11/ios/mac/PFI_MAC_2_0_1_12640.zip

There is a Windows version, but I can't post that link since I'm only allowed to post 2 hyperlinks.